# How to make an infinite loop in Lua code?

Tags: loops, lua, infinite-loop

I have three local functions that I want to use forever in memory:

```
proxy:PlayerParamRecover();
proxy:PlayerRecover();
proxy:EnableInvincible(10000,true);
```

I'm not sure how to add them in an infinite loop.

Comment: What do you mean, "use forever in memory" ?

Comment: Please note that the language is named "Lua", not "LUA". It is the proper name of the Earth's moon, in Portuguese.

Comment: If you want to edit your question, you can click the "edit" link below the tags.  Give it a try.

Comment: what game engine or environment are you working in? that seems probably important to your question

Answer (score 13):

You want a `while` loop:

```
while true do
  proxy:PlayerParamRecover()
  proxy:PlayerRecover()
  proxy:EnableInvincible(10000,true)
end
```

Additional information [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ControlStructureTutorial)

Note that, since the while loop will *always* have control of the program after entering that loop, any code you write after it won't ever execute.  Infinite loops are only useful in extreme cases - make sure that what you want to do warrants it.

Comment: One thing: you cannot write the colon after "do", that's what you would do in Python, but not in Lua

Comment: Also, no semicolons required in Lua even when you have multiple statements on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to use infinite loop:

```
repeat
-- do something
until false
```

-- or --

```
while true do
-- do something
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to say "Hello" in the command bar every second, infinitely, or something like that, you would use the format below:

```
    while true do
    -- whatever
    end
```

For example,

```
    while true do
    print("Hello")
    wait(1)
    end
```

Comment: while this is factually accurate, the above code will block the thread, and is unlikely the right solution to the person's problem