# Infinite for loop in Lua

Tags: loops, lua

Why doesn't this work in lua?

```
for i = 1, 100, -1 do
  print('Infinite')
end
```

The above loop prints nothing. From what I know from conventional languages like C/C++, the above should be an infinite loop.
C++ equivalent

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i--) 
  cout << "Infinite";
```

I want to know how exactly a `for` loop in lua works. Isn't it the same as the C++ one given above?

**Edit:** I don't want to know [How to make an infinite loop in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180010). I am more concerned here with how a `for` loop in lua works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an infinite loop in Lua code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180010/how-to-make-an-infinite-loop-in-lua-code)

Comment: See the semantics in https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5

Comment: on C++ it is no infinity loop. It should end in some time.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, the for loop has three functions just like C/C++.

```
for i = <start>, <finish>, <increment> do
```

But lua will detect that the increment will not allow the function to end and will completely ignore this loop.
To create an infinite loop, you simple use:

```
while true do
```

In lua, putting a variable as an argument with no operator will check if the value exists/is true. If it is false/nil then it will not run. In this case, true is always true because it is constant so the loop goes forever.

```
while true do
     print('Infinite Loop')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`for` is explicitly defined in Lua to check if current value is lower than limit if step is negative. Since step `-1` is negative and current value `1` is lower than limit `100` right from the start, this `for` performs no loops.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop in lua has the syntax below:

```
for init,max/min value, increment
do
   statement(s)
end
```

so the code below will print from 1 to 10:

```
for i=10,1,-1
do
   print(i)
end
```

To generate infinite loops in lua you might have to use while loops:

```
while( true )
do
   print("This loop will run forever.")
end
```

for more visit http://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_loops.htm